# Double requests before open page

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a very... strange problem,
I saw in `network` tab in chrome devtools that my vue app send double request onto this same endpoints :/

here is my code, in router section i have a function `beforeEach`, and when i navigate to `/account/projects` i launch dispatch from my vuex store to fetch data from server:

```
function fetchProjects() {
  store.dispatch("getProjects");
  store.dispatch("getFavoriteProjects");
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    //when authenticated == true, current user must be logged in to view page
    if(to.meta.authenticated) {
        if(authenticated()) {
            //when authenticated -> fetch data about current user to vuex store
            

            if(to.path == "/account/projects" || to.path == "/account") {
              fetchProjects();
            }

            store.dispatch("updateUserData").then(() => {
              next();
             });
       } else {
           //when not authenticated -> redirected to login page
           next("/auth/login");
       }
    } else {
        next();
    } 
})
```

in routes i have this:

```
{
        path: "/account/projects",
        component: () => import("@/views/account/Projects.vue"),
        meta: {
          showProgressBar: true,
          authenticated: true
        },
}
```

and in component this:

```
computed: {
    projects() {
      return this.$store.getters.getProjects;
    },
    favoriteProjects() {
      return this.$store.getters.getFavoriteProjects;
    },
}
```

in network at chrome devtools i have this:
[image]

it shows that my application sends this same request after the first requests, does anyone know why this is happening?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

based on your code you have invoked two functions such as authenticated() and fetchProjects() that get data from the server